# My DNS and web server work, but Google can't fetch it

Tags: domain-name-system, web, google

My site is http://miklcct.csproject.org/ .
I can open it in my web browser, access it from the Internet, and DNS queries from the Internet work but Google cannot fetch it.

In webmaster tools,

Google couldn't access your site because of a DNS error.

Comment: I've just found an FAQ that there is a "secret" DNS server which hides my side from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid answer: typo in webmaster tools? :)
Try also temporarily disabling the IPv6 entry for your site (though Google says it's supported).